# Ubuntu 14.04 dropping ipv6 route and ifstate

Tags: ipv6, ubuntu-14.04

i have the following issue:

i have configured my server to use IPv4 and IPv6.
everything works fine.

but now somehow IPv6 stops working.

```
ip -6 route
```

is not showing the correct routes anymore
and in `/etc/networking/ifstate` the `eth0=eth0` line is missing.
i even noticed that yesterday (when i had this issue as well) `/etc/modules` was missing `ipv6`

the only way to fix this is to do a server reboot.
for more info see https://askubuntu.com/questions/498016/ipv6-network-is-unreachable-until-reboot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static configuration in /etc/network/interfaces that you posted on askubuntu.com looks good.

Disable RAs on your server interface(s).

You can do this by adding the following line after "iface eth0 inet6 static".

pre-up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_ra

Or you can use sysctl.

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra=0

The static configuration should work. If not, try pinging the IPv6 gateway you specify in /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: what's an RA ? just asking :-)    
To improve your answer: http://superuser.com/a/33204    
Think thats it disabling auto configure..

Comment: Router advertisement. It's a fundamental component of neighbor discovery (roughly the IPv6 equivalent of ARP but with more functionality).

Comment: Looks like this works, so thanks for your time and answer.